# How do I share read-only acces to a data model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, global

I have an object on some controller's scope, bound to some inputs on the accompanying view. I want to share the data in that object with other controllers, so they can read it, but they should not be able to modify it.

It seems to me, if it put the model in a service/factory, I either allow or prevent all modification. Same thing if I put it on the rootscope.

What would be the connonical way of doing something like this?

Comment: I'd go with a service/factory.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Yeah that's what I'm doing currently. I was hoping there'd be a way to encapsulate things a bit more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the model in a service/factory, and assign getter/setter functions to it, something like:

```
angular.factory('testFactory', [function(){

    var _yourModel = {}

    return {
        yourModel: function(newValue){
            if(newValue){
                _yourModel = newValue
            }else{
                return angular.copy(_yourModel) //This will return a clone of _yourModel
            }
        }
    }

}])


//In your controller
  $scope.model = testFactory.yourModel();
```

Comment: Simple and clean. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just for a sake of this discussion . If you use `$rootscope` to store your data globally like `$rootscope.data()`. For instance, if you define `$rootScope.data()` and in a controller you define a function `$scope.data()` because you forget about the first created `data()`, something will certainly go wrong.

So best way to use this kind of scenario angular `service` is better also please bear with my english.